# Blender cycles render to unreal engine 4 problem

Tags: materials, export, workflow, import, unreal-engine

I'm pretty new to blender and have made my first mesh I want to import to ue4.  I used cycles render and when I export with fbx and import it to ue4, none of the materials are applied.  Here's a picture in blender [image: blender picture] and here's the picture from ue4. [image: ue4 picture]
I've tried recreating the materials in ue4 but just can't get the same results.  I've read stuff about baking the material into the mesh or something about light UV maps but I'm not sure how to do any of that.  If I could get some help to export my mesh with the materials that would be awesome. 
Thanks

Comment: Probably found the answer but just in case : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB09T--_ZvU

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)